# Definition of a $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

I am looking at a definition of a tensor space and came across the expression of a $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear map in the following context:

> Let $M$ and $N$ be R-module and $G$ and abelian group (i.e.
>   $\Bbb{Z}$-module). A $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear map, $\beta:M\times N\rightarrow G$ is called $R$-balanced
>   if... *(paraphrased from Wisbauer, 1988; pg90)*

What is the meaning of a $\Bbb{Z}$-bilinear map in this context? (p.s. I am asking about what the qualifier $\Bbb{Z}$ indicates - I know what a Bilinear map is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A map $f:M\times N\to A$ (for an Abelian group $A$) is
$\Bbb Z$-bilinear if
$$f(m+m',n)=f(m,n)+f(m',n)$$
and
$$f(m,n+n')=f(m,n)+f(m,n')$$
for all $m$, $m'\in M$ and all $n$, $n'\in N$.
In other words, for fixed $m$, $n\mapsto f(m,n)$ is a $\Bbb Z$-linear
map from $N$ to $A$, and ditto for the other argument.

Comment: Ok thanks, so what if it is $S$-bilinear for some ring $S$? in this case if $M$ and $N$ still $R$-module does $A$ need to be an $S$-module?

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Then you would want $A$ to be an $S$-module and $f(sm,n)=sf(m,n)=f(m,sn)$.

Comment: How can $sm$ and $sf(m,n)$ both be valid expressions? $m$ is ina $R$-module and $f(m,n)$ is in a $S$-module.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification you'd want them all to be $S$-modules, surely.

Comment: From the (paraphrased) quote I have given in my question it does seem that $M$ and $N$ are over different a ring to $G$. So it would appear that this is not the case.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification An $R$-module is, whatever ring $R$ is, also a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (by definition).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh ok, that explains it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the way I like to write it (for a commutative ring $R$):

Suppose $f:M\times N\to G$, $M,N,T$ all $R$ modules over a commutative ring $R$.

$f$ is called a *bi-additive* mapping if
$$f(m+m',n)=f(m,n)+f(m',n)$$
and
$$f(m,n+n')=f(m,n)+f(m,n')$$

$f$ is called an $R$-*bilinear mapping* if

$$f(mr,n)=rf(m,n)$$
and
$$f(m,nr)=rf(m,n)$$

for all $r\in R$.

$f$ is called an *$R$-balanced mapping* if

$$f(mr,n)=f(m,rn)$$

for all $r\in R$.

It is easy to see that when $R=\mathbb Z$, a bi-additive map is already $\mathbb Z$-bilinear and $\mathbb Z$-balanced.

Now, the last condition is the interesting one. An $R$-bilinear map might be $R$ balanced, or it might not be.  That is the difference between $M\otimes_\mathbb ZN$ and $M\otimes_R N$.

You can generalize this way out for noncommutative rings and say that if $_SM_R$ and $_RN_T$ are bimodules for rings $S,R,T$, then you can talk about bi-additive, left-$S$-linear right-$T$-linear $R$-balanced maps and the natural bimodule structure of $_S(M\otimes_R N)_T$.

Explicitly:

$$f(sm,n)=sf(m,n)$$
and
$$f(m,nt)=f(m,n)t$$
and 
$$f(mr,n)=f(m,rn)$$

for all $(r,s,t)\in R\times S\times T$.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Although this is really helpful I am not sure you explain the meaning of a $S$-bilinear map on $f:M\times N\rightarrow G$ where $M$, $N$ are $R$-module and $G$ is $S$-module  (my question was concerning this when $S$ is $\Bbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification $M\otimes_RN$ only has an $S$ module structure if one of $M$ and $N$ has an $S$ module structure.

Comment: Maybe you should be more precise in the setup, rather than just referring to "modules" since this whole story really makes a distintion between left- right- and two-sided modules.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft While admitting that I haven't been precise, I don't think that's the important thing at hand. I just wanted to paint the basic picture for commutative rings and then hint at the big picture. However, Quantum, if you think you'd like to see something like Tobais is describing, let me know and I'll invest more time in the solution.

Comment: The reason I commented was that my immediate instinct upon reading the definition was that $R$-bilinear implied $R$-balanced, until I realized that this needed the left and right structures to be the same.